# Weird glitch involving my code

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

So today, I was messing around with some examples and decided I wanted to make an app. So I attempted. When I click once, the screen becomes black, another click then white, and after some spamming the block appears, clicking again makes the background go black, another click, then white. After some more spamming there is another block inside the block, pictures are attached.

**CODE:**

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "SFML/OpenGL.hpp"
#include <GL\GLU.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "cube.cpp"

void createblock() {

    gluPerspective(90.f, 1.f, 1.f, 300.0f);
    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, -50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, 50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, 50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, -50.f, -50.f);


    glVertex3f(-50.f, -50.f, 50.f);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, 50.f, 50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, 50.f, 50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, -50.f, 50.f);

    glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, -50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, 50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, 50.f, 50.f);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, -50.f, 50.f);

    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(50.f, -50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, 50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, 50.f, 50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, -50.f, 50.f);

    glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, -50.f, 50.f);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, -50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, -50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, -50.f, 50.f);

    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, 50.f, 50.f);
    glVertex3f(-50.f, 50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, 50.f, -50.f);
    glVertex3f(50.f, 50.f, 50.f);

    glEnd();
}

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SimpleBlocks");
sf::Event maine;

int main() {

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // load defaults here

        while (window.pollEvent(maine)) {
            // events here
            if (maine.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            } 
            if (maine.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) { 
                createblock();
                window.display();

                // make block later   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**IMAGES:**

[imgur album here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQkrB.jpg)

Comment: Anyone know? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I guess it's that weird lol!

Answer (score 1):

You never call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` before you draw, so there are always leftover fragments or some overlap in depth information. Adding a clear call should fix your issue.

Comment: It didn't work... it does the same thing but no flash of black and white when ever I click. it is always grey, and it just makes the cube in random fov's

Answer (score 0):

Call `glPushMatrix` before `gluPerspective` and `glPopMatrix` at the end of `createblock`